# Get rows from DB that contains values in my list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to get all rows in my database table "Foo" that have the same "Name" as Field1 and the same "LastName" as Field2.

```
List<Field> Fields = FillFields();

public class Field 
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

db.Foo.Where(x => Fields.Any(f=> f.Field1 == x.Name && f.Field2 == x.LastName));
```

But I am getting this exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Field'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in
>   this context.

What am doing wrong?

Cant I compare like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq To EF : How to filter using Non-Primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729202/linq-to-ef-how-to-filter-using-non-primitive-types)

Comment: which Fields exactly do you want to get? if all from DB are meant, use db.Fields. if only those from the Foo watched are meant, use x.Fields.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I want to get all rows from table "Foo" that have the same "Name" as Field1 and the same "LastName" as Field2.