# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SqlHierarchyId' and 'string'

Tags: c#

How do I compare `SqlHierarchyId` type in LINQ? I tried with below

```
string input = "/1/2/";
var output = SqlHierarchyId.Parse(input);

var fileFolder = _PIMSContext.FileFolders.SingleOrDefault(f =>  f.Node == input);
```

and

```
string input = "/1/2/";
var output = SqlHierarchyId.Parse(input);

var fileFolder = _PIMSContext.FileFolders.SingleOrDefault(f =>  f.Node == output);
```

Comment: Have you tried `f.Node.Equals(output)` ?

Comment: If your SqlHierarchyId.Parse returns a non primintive type this link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729202/linq-to-ef-how-to-filter-using-non-primitive-types

Comment: What type is `Node` ? Seemingly its an `SqlHierarchyId ` and the second variation should work

Comment: Also you can try operator overloading

Comment: @MichaelRandall `SqlHierarchyId` type

Comment: @Fildor that will give another error `Error: No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId to a known managed provider native type.`

Comment: This is the operator `public static SqlBoolean operator ==(SqlHierarchyId hid1, SqlHierarchyId hid2) => ...` which will convert to `bool` , something is not what it seems...

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20415 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/365 Are you on EF Core? If so, did you try https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/365#issuecomment-614116845 ?

Comment: ^^ _"SqlHierarchyId minimally "worked" in EF Core 2.x on .NET Framework. **It is not supported on .NET Core**. Also, given that EF Core 5 will no longer run on .NET Framework, we are not currently prioritizing making SqlHierarchyId work in EF Core."_ - Oo ...

Comment: Yes, I am on EF Core 3.1.7

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/365#issuecomment-614116845 / https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId ?

Comment: @mjwills, I have installed `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` version 1.1.0